# Cloud function ends before running all code

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function, but it in the logs of firebase, it shows 'finished' before doing all the tasks.

This is my code.

```
  export const count = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('0 8 * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Brussels')
  .onRun(async context => {

     const snapshot =  await admin.database().ref('/counter').once('value');

     snapshot.forEach( (child) =>
{
    var info = child.val();
    var dayViews = info['count'];
    var ID = child.key;

        var ref1 = admin.database().ref('/counter/'+ID);
        ref1
        .update({
          "count": 0,
          "totalViews": dayViews,
        })
        .then(function() {
          console.log("Write completed")
        }).catch(function(error) {
          console.error("Write failed: "+error)
        });

    });
    return 0;

  });
```

I think the problem is that the function returns 0 before finishing the for each loop.

Is there a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to wait for all the asynchronous `update()` operations to be completed before calling return: since you use a `forEach()` loop, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in order to wait for all the asynchronous operations called in the loop to be completed before returning the Promise it returns.

As explained in the doc (link above), `Promise.all()` "is typically used after having started **multiple asynchronous tasks to run concurrently** and having created promises for their results, so that one can wait for all the tasks being finished".

The following should do the trick:

```
export const count = functions.pubsub
    .schedule('0 8 * * *')
    .timeZone('Europe/Brussels')
    .onRun(async context => {

        const snapshot = await admin.database().ref('/counter').once('value');

        const promises = [];

        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            var info = child.val();
            var dayViews = info['count'];
            var ID = child.key;

            var ref1 = admin.database().ref('/counter/' + ID);

            promises.push(ref1
                .update({
                    "count": 0,
                    "totalViews": dayViews,
                }));
        });

        return Promise.all(promises)

    });
```

---

On why it is key to correctly handle the asynchronous operations in a Cloud Function, I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the Firebase video series: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/

Comment: Thanks! The code gives no errors until I add: return Promise.all(promises); "Variable 'promises' implicitly has an 'any[]' type." When I fix this error by changing the const promises to : const promises: readonly any[] = []; The promises.push gives an error. "Property 'push' does not exist on type 'readonly any[]'." (I'm using typescript). Thanks!

Comment: @KarelDebedts give me 20/30 minutes!

Comment: Sure! No problem! Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: The [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference.html?authuser=1#update) method returns a Promise of type `Promise<any>`. Since you push a set of these Promises to the `promises` Array, you need to declare it as follows: `const promises: Promise<any>[] = [];` or as follows: `const promises: Array<Promise<any>> = [];`. See also https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-array

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort! Worked!